# How to download all VSTS code review/shelveset files

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

I would like to download all the files (over 100) that have been submitted to me for code review.

I know I can download single files, but that would be to slow. Can I just download all the files in the code review's shelveset? We are using VS2015 and VS version control (not GIT).

Comment: Downloading the shelveset items one at a time is _so_ slow. 100 files? 2-3 minutes easy. On a LAN.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the files programmatically through VSTS Rest API: [Get shelveset changes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/shelvesets#get-shelveset-changes) and [Get a file](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/items#get-a-file).

Simple sample to do it through PowerShell:

```
function DownloadShelvesetFiles{
param(
[string]$shelveUrl
)
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f 'test','[personal access token]')))
$shelveChanges = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $shelveUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
foreach($c in $shelveChanges.value){
$filepath=$c.item.path -replace "\$","D:/shelveFiles"
$folderPath=$filepath.subString(0,$filePath.LastIndexof("/"))
if(!(Test-Path -PathType Container $folderPath)){
   new-item -ItemType Directory -force $folderPath
}
  Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $c.item.url -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} | Out-File -filepath $filepath
}
}

DownloadShelvesetFiles -shelveUrl "https://XXX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/tfvc/shelvesets/CodeReview_2017-10-20_10.00.50.5978;af97843e-4341-49f4-a11d-283a7ba6da57/changes?maxChangeCount=100&api-version=1.0-preview.1"
```

Comment: Hi @starain-MSFT thank you for the sample. Looks like what I need. However I am unsure how to go about authentication? We have integrated single sign based on Azure AD running.

Comment: @Karl You can use [personal access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate). (replace [personal access token] to your token)

Comment: @Karl What's the result after you trying it with personal access token?

Comment: Hi thanks for that. I managed to work out that the token is generated and available in the VSTS web portal. Thats the bit I was missing. It now works. Although the code above fails on folders... I am busy updating it and will port one done.

Comment: Yes I have, but now am struggling with some files that are not downloaded properly. It seems to be files that are added and not amended in the shelveset. i.e. when downloading the file it get meta data of the file, not the file itself.

Comment: @Karl Check the REST API result of related shelveset, then access the corresponding URL (in REST API result) and check the content manually.

Comment: not sure why you say "Check the REST API result of related shelveset"

Comment: @Karl I mean get the shelveset (has the issue) through Get shelveset changes REST API.

Comment: The op says they dont want to download the files one at a time because that is slow. This example shows how to download the files one at a time.